# Waiting for all Consumers to be in the waiting state in a Producer and Multi-Consumer implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading, monitor, producer-consumer, thread-synchronization

### Background

I have implemented a piece of code in C# which is the equivalent of a producer with many consumers using the Monitor's Wait and PulseAll methods.

I would like to provide the option for the producer to wait before producing until all consumers are waiting.

This is the simplified implementation of the consumer side:

```
lock (_lock)
{
    while (! _condition)
    {
        Monitor.Wait(_lock);
    }
}
```

And this is the simplified implementation on the producer side:

```
lock (_lock)
{
    _condition = true;
    Monitor.PulseAll(_lock);
}
```

This is a well known pattern which is fairly efficient and works well in my case.

### The Problem

In some cases I would like to be able to have the producer wait before calling the producer code above until all consumers are inside the `Monitor.Wait()` call.

### Solution Concept for Single Consumer

Let us simplify the question for the case of a single consumer.
The solution requires that the producer wait on an additional synchronization object that the consumer can signal atomically with its entrance to `Monitor.Wait()`.

### Solution Concept for Multiple Consumers

Generalizing the above solution, all consumers need to access a thread safe counter which is initialized with the number of consumers.

Each consumer will atomically call  `Monitor.Wait()` and decrement the counter. Also within the atomic call each consumer will check whether the counter is zero after the decrement and if so reinitialize the counter and signal the producer.

### Summary

in a Producer and Multi-Consumer implementation in C# I need to allow the producer to wait for all Consumers to be in the waiting state before producing.

I have not found a way to implement this based on Monitors.

I would prefer a solution based on Monitors but if an entirely different approach would make this simpler, that would also be great.

Comment: What makes it important for the producer to wait until every consumer is in the waiting state?

Comment: Well yes, you've described your solution already, which should work just fine. You want a variable "working consumers" that's updated in your lock by the consumers according to their state. When that reaches 0 signal the producer. Don't use two locks and this should be pretty straightforward. What problem do you have?

Comment: @Voo This does not work.
On the consumer side I changed the wait so:\

Comment: @David What doesn't work? Keeping the counter accurate is simple (increment before the work callback, decrement and check if 0 afterwards) and then it's just signaling the producer.

Comment: @Voo Sorry, the comment slipped before completion. On the consumer side I now have this:
```
lock (_lock)
{
    while (! _condition)
    {
        // added
        _waiting++;
        Monitor.PulseAll(_lock);
        // end
        
        Monitor.Wait(_lock);
        _waiting--;
    }
}
```
and on the producer side: 
```
lock (_lock)
{ 
    // added
    while (_waiting != 1)
    {
        Monitor.Wait(_lock);
    }
    // end added
    _condition = true;
    Monitor.PulseAll(_lock);
}
```

Comment: @Voo No markdown in comments?
Well, the effect is that the producer does not wait. I am debugging it now.

Comment: @Voo the problem is that after the consumer increments waiting it then goes into its wait, atomically releasing the lock. It only decrements the waiting count AFTER it wakes from the wait, so at this point, the counter might be equal to consumerCount and the lock is not taken. So the producer will not need to wait in order to produce again.

Comment: @David The counter should be "consumers *working*" which avoids this problem ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202000/discussion-between-david-sackstein-and-voo).

Comment: It appears you want to implement one of the patterns in https://sworthodoxy.blogspot.com/2015/05/shared-resource-design-patterns.html. In particular look at the pattern titled "squad lock".

Comment: Looks like a great site. I will take a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CountdownEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.countdownevent?view=netframework-4.8) for this, the consumers should signal the event, then the producer can wait to enter the lock until the countdown reaches zero.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Jennings.
I tried this out and could not find the correct place to reset the countdown event. In one place it caused a deadlock and in another the reset invalidated the signal before the producer had waited on it. Can you propose a code update to demonstrate the idea?

Comment: Why is it important that the producer wait for all the consumers to be in the waiting state? What goes wrong if the producer produces a value with no waiting consumers?

Comment: It is possible that I have analyzed the needs incorrectly. I am reviewing now. Thank you.